# Only one column to fit its content size while other stretching

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

I have a table that looks like this:

```
  |   column1   |   column2    |   column 3
-------------------------------------------
1 | name1       | value1       |  class1
2 | name2       | value2       |  class2
3 | name3       | value3       |  class3
```

I've defined table widget as:

```
ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);
ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(3);
ui->tableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderLabels({"column1", "column2", "column3"});
ui->tableWidget->setItem(currentRow, 0, new QTableWidgetItem(name));
ui->tableWidget->setItem(currentRow, 1, new QTableWidgetItem(values.toString()));
ui->tableWidget->setItem(currentRow, 3, new QTableWidgetItem(class));
```

I would like for my table to look like this:

```
  |   column1   |column2|   column 3
-------------------------------------------
1 | name1       |value1 |  class1
2 | name2       |value2 |  class2
3 | name3       |value3 |  class3
```

How can I achieve having only `column2` (along with its values) to fit its content?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with an overload of [`setSectionResizeMode`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#setSectionResizeMode-1) that takes the column index as first argument:

```
ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(1, QHeaderView::Fixed);
```

Then, after inserting all items, call [`resizeColumnToContents`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#resizeColumnToContents) on the fixed-size column to adjust its width.

Here the complete code:

```
ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(3);
ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);
ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(1, QHeaderView::Fixed);
ui->tableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderLabels({"column1", "column2", "column3"});

// Insert items here...

ui->tableWidget->resizeColumnToContents(1);
```

You can find the full example in [GitHub](https://github.com/cbuchart/stackoverflow/tree/master/56925947-only-one-column-to-fit).